# How do I configure the "Processing R Provider"-Plugin in QGIS 3.10 on Linux Mint

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, linux

I am using the "Processing R Provider"-Plugin in QGIS 3.10 running on Linux Mint 18. I have R installed, but QGIS is not able to find it:

[image]

[image]

R is installed in "/user/bin":

[image]

I have already tried to adjust the "R Folder" link in the Processing Options, but to no avail:

[image]

According to the QGIS [manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html#r-scripts) QGIS should know where R is, if I can run "R" by typing R in the terminal and that works.

[image]

But QGIS still prompts "This algorithm cannot be run".

If i run an empty R-Script I get:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe Qgis doesn't have the right to access /usr/bin
Try launching Qgis in root. In a terminal : ```sudo qgis```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that. But it didn't work. But maybe the problem occurs because i am using the flatpak version of QGIS?

Comment: In the end I deinstalled the flatpak version and reinstalled the regular version and it worked!